# Drag and dropping multiple items deletes entire data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a grid that loads data from a JSON file. When the user presses ctrl on an item the item receives a new property `selected`. I want to be able to drag and drop the flagged items together somewhere in the grid. Currently, my code works, however when the multiple items are dropped the entire data disappears. This occurs because only the selected items are being spliced but how can I drag and drop the multiple selected files and keep my data?

Here is my main.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DragAndDrop } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
import { DraggableRow } from './draggable-row';
import { Checkbox } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';
import { DragHandleCell } from './drag-handle-cell';
import products from './products.json';
import {
  groupBy,
  GroupDescriptor,
  GroupResult,
} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

export const ReorderContext = React.createContext({
  reorder: () => {},
  dragStart: () => {},
});

const App = () => {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = React.useState(products);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState(null);

  const reorder = (dataItem, direction) => {
    if (activeItem === dataItem) {
      return;
    }

    let reorderedData = gridData.slice();

    console.log(reorderedData);

    let selectedItems = reorderedData.filter((el) => {
      return el.selected === true;
    });

    console.log(selectedItems);

    let prevIndex = selectedItems.findIndex((p) => p === activeItem);
    let nextIndex = selectedItems.findIndex((p) => p === dataItem);

    selectedItems.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    selectedItems.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? -1 : 0), 0),
      0,
      activeItem || selectedItems[0]
    );
    setGridData(selectedItems);
  };

  const dragStart = (dataItem) => {
    setActiveItem(dataItem);
  };

  return (
    <ReorderContext.Provider
      value={{
        reorder: reorder,
        dragStart: dragStart,
      }}
    >
      <DragAndDrop>
        <Grid
          style={{
            height: '400px',
          }}
          data={gridData}
          dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
          rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
            <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
          )}
        >
          <Column title="" width="80px" cell={DragHandleCell} />
          {/* <Column title="" width="80px" cell={CustomCell} /> */}
          <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
          <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
          <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
          <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
          <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
        </Grid>
      </DragAndDrop>
    </ReorderContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

and here is my draggable row code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReorderContext } from './main';
import { useDraggable, useDroppable } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
export const DraggableRow = (props) => {
  const [dropped, setDropped] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragged, setDragged] = React.useState(false);
  const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(null);
  const selectedItems = [];
  const [initial, setInitial] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const { dragStart, reorder } = React.useContext(ReorderContext);
  const element = React.useRef(null);

  const handlePress = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
      element.current.style.color = 'red';
      props.dataItem.selected = true;
    }
    setInitial({
      x: event.clientX - event.offsetX,
      y: event.clientY - event.offsetY,
    });
  };

  const handleDragStart = (event) => {
    if (
      !event.originalEvent.target ||
      !event.originalEvent.target.dataset.dragHandle
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setDragged(true);
    dragStart(props.dataItem);
  };

  const handleDrag = (event) => {
    if (!element.current || !dragged) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = `translateY(${
      event.clientY - initial.y + event.scrollY
    }px)`;
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    setDragged(false);
    setDropped(false);
    setInitial({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    });
  };

  const handleRelease = () => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = null;
  };

  const handleDragEnter = () => {
    setDropped(true);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    const rect = element.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setDirection(
      rect.top + rect.height / 2 <= event.pageY ? 'after' : 'before'
    );
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDrop = () => {
    reorder(props.dataItem, direction);
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  useDraggable(
    element,
    {
      onPress: handlePress,
      onDragStart: handleDragStart,
      onDrag: handleDrag,
      onDragEnd: handleDragEnd,
      onRelease: handleRelease,
    },
    {
      autoScroll: dragged,
    }
  );
  useDroppable(element, {
    onDragEnter: handleDragEnter,
    onDragOver: handleDragOver,
    onDragLeave: handleDragLeave,
    onDrop: handleDrop,
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {dropped && direction === 'before' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
      <tr
        {...props.elementProps}
        ref={element}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          userSelect: 'none',
          pointerEvents: dragged ? 'none' : undefined,
          opacity: dragged ? '0.8' : undefined,
        }}
      />
      {dropped && direction === 'after' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

and here is an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv2hnu-epuasf?file=app/products.json

Answer (score 0):

**Misread the initial post, updated answer in comments**

```
let selectedItems = reorderedData.filter((el) => {
  return el.selected;
});
```

None of reordered data has a `selected` property.
This result in a empty `selectedItems` array.

Then you insert your activeItem in the empty array :

```
selectedItems.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? -1 : 0), 0),
      0,
      activeItem || selectedItems[0]
    );
```

This results in the fact that you only have the activeItem in the list after the drop.

Comment: So I should put a selected field in each item and set it to true/false?

Comment: Yes that would work with the items that are `selected: true` but I'm not sure why you want to have a selected property ?

Comment: So that I know when a user has pressed Ctrl, thus selecting more than one item and move them.

Comment: I updated my code and example by setting a selected property initially set to false and then I change it to true once Ctrl has been pressed, but the data is still deleted. @Mteuahasan

Comment: Sorry I did not read you post well in the first time.
This is quite a mess but I updated my answer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv2hnu-38tcem?file=app%2Fmain.jsx
We have to deal really different if the select multiple feature is used.
My code does not handle the fact that the user can select two not consecutive items. You should definitely block this behavior IMO.